# ActionMailer Crashes Rails With Delayed Job

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid, actionmailer, delayed-job

Using rails 3.2.5, ruby 1.9.2-p290, delayed_job 3.0.3, and delayed_job_mongoid 2.0.0 and when i run:

```
MyMailer.delay.signup_email(user)
```

We get:

> ruby(20929,0x7fff73dff180) malloc: *** error for object
>   0x7fa25a4f6d80: pointer being freed was not allocated
>   *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug Abort trap: 6

Here is the mailer:

```
class MyMailer < ActionMailer::Base   
  default :from => "support@myapp.com"

  def signup_email(user)
    @user = user
    mail( :to => user.email,
          :subject => "Welcome" )   
  end 
end
```

Has anyone else seen this? Ive try bundle updating but that didnt seem to help.

Comment: shouldn't it be :to=> @user.email ?

Comment: Seen many times. Happens to me occasionally on mac. The culprit in my case is the mail-style gem, which uses Nokogiri, which uses libxml, which is at the root of the problem. No solution yet found have I.